# Zebra_Dialog - Get input texbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a Zebra_Dialog modal window as a small form for user input. However, when retrieving the textbox values, it returns a blank string every time. This is what I'm using to create the pop-up:

```
new $.Zebra_Dialog("<table><tr><td>Request ID:</td><td><input id='txtRequest' type='text' /></td></tr><tr><td>Request Title:</td><td><input id='txtTile' type='text' /></td></tr></table>", {
    'type': 'information',
    'title': 'Save Estimate',
    'buttons':
        [
            {
                caption: 'Submit', callback: function () {
                    UploadToDB();
                    return false;
                }
            },
            {
                caption: 'Cancel', callback: function () {
                }
            }
        ]
});
```

When the `UploadToDB` method fires it has this code to get the value from the dynamically created textboxes:

```
function UploadToDB() {
    var param = {
        requestID: document.getElementById("txtRequest").value,
        requestTitle: document.getElementById("txtTitle").value
    };
//Other code here.....
}
```

I've also tried different variations such as `requestID: $("#txtRequest").val(),`.

Every time though I get a blank string back. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you click, are you sure UploadToDB is firing? Can you debug and see whether the field values get put into the param variable, and do you get an empty string back for both items?

Comment: Definitely firing, its grabbing a bunch of other values from outside the zebra_dialog with no issue

Comment: I did notice a typo in the html: <input id='txtTile' type='text' /> txtTitle mis-spelt. Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Got excited for a second... no cigar though. There is a typo but that isnt the issue

Comment: Could it be that UploadToDB is getting the values of the input's as they were when the Zebra_Dialog was instantiated? Not quite sure why this would happen though. Is your code enclosed within a "$(document).ready(function() { ... });" block? I'm just thinking it could be to do with the order in which things are loaded as the page is rendered.

Comment: If you were to put the "var param = {..." code directly in the submit callback as opposed in it's own function, does this make any difference?

Comment: Tricky one this. Does using something like $("table > tr > td > input#txtRequest").val() make any difference?

Comment: When you run this, do any errors appear in firebug or IE F12 or chrome dev tools in the console tab at all?

Comment: No errors when debugging, running some of those other scenarios now, ty

Answer (score 1):

I really like Zebra_Dialog, so I wrote these helper functions.  zprompt() is the one you want, it turns out to be a little tricky to get Zebra to handle prompt, and I couldn't get zprompt or zconfirm to act like synchronous Javascript functions prompt or confirm which is why they have callbacks.  The OP has the same problem I had, which is that the text input vanishes on closure and jquery cannot get its value, that's why I use the old-fashioned onchange handler below.

```
function zalert(msg,title,type) {
  $.Zebra_Dialog(msg,"title":title||'Alert',"type":type||'error',"position":['center','top+50']});
}

function zconfirm(msg,title,okproc) {
    $.Zebra_Dialog(msg,{
        'type':     'question',
        'title':    title||'Confirm?',
        'position': ['center','top+50'],
        'buttons':  ['OK','Cancel'],
        'onClose':  function(caption) {
                       if (caption=="OK")
                          okproc();
                    }
    });
}

var zprompt_value='';
function zprompt(msg,deftxt,title,okproc) {
   var len=deftxt.length;
   var wd=len*10;
   if (wd<220) wd=300;
   var size=len || 24;
   $.Zebra_Dialog(msg,{
       'title':    title||'Confirm?',
       'message':  msg+"<br><input type=text onchange='zprompt_value=this.value' value='"+deftxt+"' size="+size+">",
       'width':    wd,
       'position': ['center','top+50'],
       'buttons':  ['OK','Cancel'],
       'onClose':  function(caption) {
                      if (caption=="OK")
                         okproc(zprompt_value);
                   }
});
```

Here are some examples how they might be called:

```
zalert("Big mistake!","Report","error");

zconfirm("Are you sure you want to format the drive?","Confirm?",function(){
    format_drive();  //  Ack!
});

zprompt("Enter a funny nickname:","(nickname)","Nickname",function(n){
    set_nickname(n); 
});
```

Hope that helps someone, it took most of an afternoon to figure it out!  If there's a better way to do it, please tell me.

SSF